# NodeJS/Express Request Entity Too Large - Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an explanation about this, this is what Heroku is showing in my logs:

```
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]: Error: Request Entity Too Large
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.error (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:44:13)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.limit [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/limit.js:45:47)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.logger [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:157:5)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.favicon [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/favicon.js:78:7)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:31:5)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]:     at Object.query [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:44:5)
45:45+00:00 app[web.7]: POST /mls 413 1ms - 980
```

I've included the last log record because I'm not sure if it suggests the HTTP URL where these errors happened, or if it's the URL of the next request the Heroku dyno is processing (we receive hundreds of requests a second so it's a bit crazy to track).

My application (**ExpressJS**) requires receiving large POST requests, which is why I've put

```
app.use(express.limit('5mb'));
```

at the top of the app to allow large post requests (usually less than 2MB). I'm not sure if the errors above are being caused by receiving a request that's too large or trying to send a request to S3 that's too large, or something else. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, this is the limit middleware, but you are probably doing something wrong if this is being logged to the console. these are "handled" errors - no need to log them.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Express v4+ you can do:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '5mb'}));
```

Or you can try the following single line solution, but I haven't personally tested

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));
```

Comment: for me i had to do `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));`

Comment: Could you please tell me the what will be the result of above two code? Because i am having the same problem with Oracle MCS and I am not using express

Comment: First `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, then `app.use(bodyParser({limit: '5mb'}));`. Or you can try Jayen online solution, but I didn't personally tested -> `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));`

Answer (score 1):

While the solution `app.use(bodyParser({limit: '5mb'}));` works in some cases, it won't work well if you have a lot of ampersand `&` in the content you are trying to upload. This is because the body parser will split based on `&`. The solution that worked for me is to replace all occurrences of `&` with `encodeURIComponent('&')` using Regex.
So you have:

```
contentToUpload = contentToUpload .replace(/&/g, encodeURIComponent('&'))
```