# Request-URI Too Long in heroku nodejs

Tags: request-uri

I am getting the following error when calling a REST API hosted on heroku, written in nodejs.

I tried all the options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627573/nodejs-express-request-entity-too-large-heroku), but it looks like that issue is different and hence is not helping.

I am using nodejs, expressjs, bodyparser.

This is working fine on my local machine, but is giving this error in heroku.

POST  414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Heroku is locked to 8kb on limit request line

> The request line of the HTTP request is limited to 8192 bytes

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#http-validation-and-restrictions